# How to Build the Executable Statically via Ndk-build?

Tags: android, gcc, static, android-ndk, ndk-build

I‘m trying to build a executable that linking android system library statically in windows, I use the following command：

```
%NDK_PATH%\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe jni\main.c -o main --sysroot=%NDK_PATH%\platforms\android-9\arch-arm -static
```

Sometime maybe need to add options:

```
 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -std=gnu99
```

The output file is what I want after building.
But if I want to build the executable use **jni\Android.mk** and **jni\Application.mk** via **ndk-build**, which option:

```
-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -std=gnu99
```

should I append and which **.mk** file should I choose?
I try to add：

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -static
```

into the **jni\Andorid.mk**, but the output is not changed.

How to solve the **.mk** problem?

Comment: `-static-libstd++` is irrelevant for C99, isn't it?

Comment: Actually just need the option **'-static'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use in your **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -static
```

The result is not *identical* to the simple **gcc** one-liner, but **arm-linux-androideabi-nm** reports no dynamic symbols for me.

Comment: I try to add the option into my Android.mk, it work. But it cause some linker error about **ld**: it cannot linking to some function like:**dlopen**, **dlsym**. I can't find the libld.a from the **ndk**, should I build a libld.a via **Android Bionic**?

Comment: No idea about `libdl.a`. What's wrong with `libdl.so` that is part of NDK?

Comment: **libdl.so** is ok. But I just want to use **.a**. Maybe I should find some way to build the libdl.a or find some Substitute function.

Comment: I think the reason why **libdl** is distributed as **.so** is to provide a platform-independent API. For **libdl.a** you should check binary compatibility with all system versions. I never tried.

Comment: Thank for helping. Now I try to use **mmap** to replace **libdl**'s function.

Comment: Android filesystem also has .so, so I wander why is it that I manage to run only static build on android ?